# Generating samples from a categorical proposal distribution with specific output (sample) structure

Tags: categorical-data, discrete-data, discrete-distributions, discrete-optimization

I'll caveat this question with that I do not think what I want to do is possible but suggestions in the right direction would be most helpful.

Now my data consists of vectors of length six, where each element is discrete, here are some examples:

```
[(0, 12, 7, 7, 12, 0),
 (11, 16, 2, 2, 16, 11),
 (8, 7, 3, 3, 7, 8),
 (13, 5, 9, 9, 5, 13),
 (0, 12, 2, 2, 12, 0),
 (11, 2, 0, 0, 2, 11),
 (11, 5, 8, 8, 5, 11),
 (8, 11, 4, 4, 11, 8),
 (7, 11, 10, 10, 11, 7),
 (16, 7, 4, 4, 7, 16)]
```

Each position can take a value in [0,16]. Fitting a categorical distribution to this data is trivial. My problem is instead that I require the output, the sample, to have a certain symmetry.

As you can see above each vector has reflective symmetry about the center of each array. Each vector is a a palindrome.

Now, I require some form of PMF from whence I can sample, but where those samples can be random in all aspects but the order in which the elements appear - is this possible?

With numpy we can of course do e.g.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.choice(range(17),1,[1/6.]*6)
```

But this will not produce a symmetric sample as it stands. One idea I had was that one could sample half an array and concatenate a reversed sample of that same array to produce the 'sample' but I suppose I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: "One idea I had was that one could sample half an array and concatenate a reversed sample" <- this sounds like an ideal solution. Assuming length 6, your vector $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_6)$ only has 3 independent ("independent" in a loose term, depending on whether or not you sample with replacement) elements - $x_1=x_6$, $x_2=x_5$, $x_3=x_4$. So sample the first three elements and then flip them to make the last three.

Comment: Building on @AlexJ's comment, is there a reason why you need to generate these 3-element vectors randomly, instead of generating all possible vectors of 3 elements? ($16^3$, which hopefully isn't computationally expensive to generate).

Comment: @J-J-J I just added a little toy example to illustrate the problem. Certainly we could enumerate all combinations. The real usage of this though is orders of magnitude larger why I am looking to exploit any symmetry I can.